# Magento 1.9.3 Не отображается атрибут в товаре

Tags: magento, атрибуты

Здравствуйте. 
Есть следующая картина:
**Magento 1.9.3 и установленная Sample data.**
Есть набор атрибутов например **Shoes**, через Manage **Attributes Sets** я добавил новый атрибут в набор атрибутов **Shoes**, если конкретно то **Manufacturer** в секцию **General**. По идее когда я после этого захожу в **Manage Products** и выбираю товар с набором атрибутов **Shoes** то там должен отображаться ранее добавленный мною атрибут **Manufacturer**, но он не отображается или я что-то не понимаю. Пробовал так и с другим атрибутом (**Size**), но так же ничего не видно. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по дефолту атрибут "manufacturer" предназначен только для "simple product" как в изображение, может ваш товар другого типа?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте реиндекс. После добавления новых атрибутов всегда нужно делать реиндекс